# Manage Events fatal error after upgrading from 5.4 to 5.10

Tags: error, 5.10.x

I am running Civi on Drupal.
After upgrading from 5.4.0 to 5.10.0
I go to Manage Events page and get this:

Fatal error: Call to undefined method CRM_Event_BAO_Event::getAllPermissions() in /home/tamera/www/dev/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Event/Page/ManageEvent.php on line 339

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see that the `getAllPermissions()` method is present, so if you're getting a "call to undefined method" error you very likely have either an extension or a customization that's overriding the file `<civiroot>/CRM/Event/BAO/Event.php`.

Turn on debugging and backtrace (**Administer menu » System Settings » Debugging and Error Handling**) and this error should become much more detailed.  If you're not sure how to interpret the backtrace to find your customizations, you can edit your question to include the backtrace and someone will likely be able to help.

Comment: I've done that (thanks, I didnt know that's possible). But still, nothing changed in the error message. I added also these:

&backtrace=1&smartyDebug=1

and still I only get the 1-line error message.

I also removed all my extensions, and disabled the only 2 that are left (CiviDiscount and CiviRules), and nothing helped.

Any other idea?

Comment: @Elad Check the file I mention in my answer above; does it have the `getAllPermissions()` function?  Is it possible that somehow (perhaps due to file permissions) not all the files were replaced when you upgraded?

Comment: Hey, I was somehow sure that I didn't have a customization in that area, but I did. Event.php was overridden by a customization. Thank you!